# accsessing picasa using android

Tags: android, google-api, picasa, google-api-java-client

I am trying to access picasa from android ,

i have tried to run following sample code

```
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/picasa-atom-android-sample/?repo=samples#picasa-atom-android-sample%3Fstate%3Dclosed
```

but i am getting only one thing over here ,

[image]

and there is no options to select google account.

in my code i am getting

```
    final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    final int size = accounts.length;
```

size = 0 and no items were there in select google account

so can you please tell me how to set up google account , to access picasa album 
or if someone has another idea then also i don't mind.

Comment: Doesn't Android already sync your picasa web albums into your gallery?

Comment: sorry didn't get u , i m running this sample on Android simulator, and apart from that gallery in my android simulator has no photos.

Comment: If you are running this in the emulator I think you are not able to setup a complete google account to access picasa. 

Try testing this on a real phone.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

There are two options for running this sample:

1. Run it on a real phone.
2. Run it on an emulator with a virtual device based on target "Google API's (Google Inc.) - API Level 8".  This is the only target that will work (as of the writing of this answer).

When the emulator starts, you need to add a Google Account before starting the sample.

For more details, please take a look a the [instructions for the sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default).

Comment: Thanks , for the answer , i added my google account in my emulator using settings. but i want to know that is this sample code displays image i can see the album name only ?